# File::Find and $_ in nested subroutines

Tags: perl, find, arguments, implicit, subroutine

When running the following code, the filenames of all files below C:\Test are printed. Why doesn't it print just `Hello` (n times, depending on how many files are processed)?

Does this imply that I cannot rely on `shift` to reliably assign to `$_`? Imagine a coworker implements the `wtf` function and doesn't know that it's called from a `File::Find` *wanted* sub.
I run this code with Strawberry Perl 5.12

Edit: This code doesn't run as expected either:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

wanted();

sub wanted{
    wtf("Hello");
}

sub wtf {
    shift;
    print; #expecting Hello 
}
```

So I guess I'm totally off the highway here.. This has obviously nothing to do with File::Find, I'm now looking for a new title for this question. Here's my original code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

find(\&wanted, "C:\\test");

sub wanted{
    wtf("Hello");
}

sub wtf {
    shift;
    print; #expecting Hello 
}
```

Comment: Try perldoc -f shift - what in it made you think that shift assigns to $_?

Comment: I have no idea. I just had this two-liner in mind: shift; print;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print` defaults to printing `$_`, but `shift` defaults to shifting `@_`. If you want to get the arguments passed to a subroutine, you should be using `@_`, not `$_`. `shift` returns the shifted value, so you should be doing something like this:

```
sub wtf {
    my $_ = shift;
    print;
}
```

The issue is that your `$_` variable is set to the filename but `@_` is set to the arguments. The [CPAN documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.1/lib/File/Find.pm#The_wanted_function) for `File::Find` explains this in detail.

Comment: No biggie. Perl is just confusing.

Answer (score 2):

[`shift` does not assign to `$_`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html).

Comment: See my comment on jasonmp85's answer.

Answer (score 0):

By the way there are better replacements for File::Find at CPAN - (for example: File::Find::Rules or File::Find::Object).  File::Find is really a kind of fossil from the old times petrified by the fact that it got into the core.